# css align-text: center for all devices media query

Tags: css

I wonder why isn't the first h1 the same as the second (h1 in @media attribute) ? only the first is working while the second is aligning to the left (when deleting the first h1 tag). help appreciated!

```
<style>
h1{
       text-align: center;
       }
       
    @media screen and(max-width:1050px){

        h1{
            text-align: center;
          }
}
</style>
```

Comment: You invalidated the syntax, by leaving out the mandatory white space between `screen and` and `(max-width:1050px)` …

Comment: and of course I mean the second only is expected to work for the set screen size and below .No other screen sizes media queries set whatsoever. so second h1 is expected to be left aligned (when first h1 is deleted) on larger screens. but is left aligned on smaller than 1050 (when adjusting the screen) or inspect.

Comment: You have set max-width for your h1. Now if the width exceeds, h1 will be rendered in the left as its default behaviour.

Comment: _“No other screen sizes media queries set whatsoever.”_ - not only “no other”, you currently have no media query _at all_ (because of the invalid syntax.)

Comment: krishan-tandon: yes i understand that part :) but it was left aligned on smaller screens as well.

Comment: Show us an example where it was, then

Comment: CBroe!  thanks you solved it!! thanks for your help! - > !# a syntax issue as it so often happens to be! :)